# Disable All Children of Disabled Category for Store View

Tags: magento2

I have a complicated category tree and a multi-store setup, with all categories currently enabled for all categories/subcategories.

For each store view, I'd like to disable specific categories and then automatically (possibly performed by script?) disable all of the children of the disabled categories -- and only for that particular view.

This is obviously achievable manually, going one-by-one, but there are too many subcategories and the tree is too complex to do this by hand. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: You can disable using direct mysql queries.

Comment: Take DB BACK UP and then try this one 
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `entity_id` IN ({{add category id's by comma separate }}) AND `attribute_id`=(SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = "is_active");

Comment: Thanks @KarangarMeghnathi -- does the above take store codes into consideration?

Comment: Yes, But in the above query For all, store it disabled.

Comment: Just you can add the store id condition
UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int SET value = '1' WHERE entity_id IN ({{add category id's by comma separate }}) AND store_id IN ({{add store id's by comma separate }}) AND attribute_id=(SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "is_active")