# How to disable all categories via programatically in magento 2

Tags: category, magento2.3.1, sub-categories

I have tried to disable categories in Magento 2

I have tried to achieve this via PHP script like below

```
<?php 

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');
$categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //categories from current store will be fetched
echo count($categories);
foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category_id = $category->getId();
    echo $category_id."<br>";

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $collection = $objectManager ->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category_id);
    $collection->setData('is_active', 0);
    $collection->save();
    echo "success";
}
?>
```

But I got following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException:
> Invalid URL key in
> /var/www/html/vkm/vendor/magento/module-catalog-url-rewrite/Observer/CategoryUrlPathAutogeneratorObserver.php:93

Please provide a solution to disable categories in Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have tried to edit directly in database like below and I have achieved what I want based on [Disable All Children of Disabled Category for Store View](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/244001/disable-all-children-of-disabled-category-for-store-view)

UPDATE catalog_category_entity_int SET value = '0' WHERE entity_id IN ({{add category id's by comma separate }}) AND attribute_id=(SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "is_active");